# The random variable $F(X,V)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, where $F(x,v) = P(X<x) + v P(X=x)$ and $V$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and independent of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is one question in my probability class exercises:

Prove that the random variable $U = F(X,V)$ is  Uniform(0,1) where

$F(x,v) = P_X(X<x) + v P_X(X=x)$

and random variables $X$ and $V$ are independent with $V$ Uniform(0,1). We haven't really covered multiple random variables yet so I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: here $X$ is a discrete random variable and $P_X(X < x)$ gives its cumulative distribution while $P_X(X = x)$ gives the probability mass function.

Comment: What does the notation $P_X(\cdot)$ mean here?

Comment: @Math1000 I'm sorry I forgot to mention that X is a discrete random variable.  $P_X(X<x)$ gives its cumulative distribution while $P_X(X=x)$ gives the probability mass function

Comment: The quantities $P_X(X<x)$ and $P_X(X=x)$ should be written $P(X<x)$ and $P(X=x)$ respectively.

Comment: @Did thanks, I didn't know that. Is this because it's discrete? The reason I've posted it like that is the exercise has it written that way.

Comment: No, discrete or not does not matter here. Usually, $P$ denotes the probability of the probability triplet $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and, if $X:\Omega\to(S,\mathcal S)$ is a random variable with values in $S$, then $P_X$ denotes the distribution of $X$, that is, a probability measure on $\mathcal S$. Since $A=\{X<x\}$ for example, is in $\mathcal F$, not in $\mathcal S$, $P(X<x)=P(A)$ is correct and $P_X(X<x)=P_X(A)$ is absurd.

Comment: I don't understand the notation here - wouldn't $$F(X,V) = P(X<X) + VP(X=X) $$ which simply reduces to $V$?

Comment: @Math1000 I thought it wouldn't because X is the random variable and x is the value of it. At least that's my interpretation. Not sure if correct.

Comment: @Math1000 The OP took care to write this correctly, and no, $F(X,V)$ is **not** what you say. Similarly, the CDF $G$ of a random variable $Y$ is defined by $$G(y)=P(Y\leqslant y)$$ for every $y$ but $G(Y)$ is certainly not almost surely $$P(Y\leqslant Y)=1$$ The closest one can come to your idea is that $$G(Y)=P(Y'\leqslant Y\mid Y)$$ where $Y'$ is a copy of $Y$, independent of $Y$.

Comment: Ah, well the post had a $<$ sign instead of a $\leqslant$ sign. I think we can agree that $\mathbb P(X<X)=0$, yes?

Comment: @Math1000 Again, this is irrelevant. Did you read my last comment to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $x$ such that $P(X=x)\ne 0$, conditionally on $\{X=x\}$, $U$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[P(X<x),P(X\leqslant x)]$, with density $$f_{U\mid X}(\ \mid x)=\frac{\mathbf 1_{(P(X<x),P(X\leqslant x))}}{P(X=x)}$$ hence the density of $U$ is $$f_U(\ )=\sum_xf_{U\mid X}(\ \mid x)P(X=x)=\sum_x\mathbf 1_{(P(X<x),P(X\leqslant x))}=\mathbf 1_B(\ )$$ where $$B=\bigcup_x(P(X<x),P(X\leqslant x))$$ Now, $$[0,1]\setminus B=\{t\in[0,1]\mid\exists x, P(X\leqslant x)=t, P(X=x)\ne0\}$$ is at most countable hence its Lebesgue measure is zero and $f_U=\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}$ Lebesgue-almost everywhere, as desired.